# How to change a id key value of record within customization code

Tags: acumatica

I need to be able to change the Project ID (Contract.ContractCD in the db) in an Acumatica customization through code and without showing a user dialog. This should be straightforward, but it doesn't seem to be. From what I gather so far, I think I need to create a PXChangeID action like the existing one in the ProjectEntry graph that opens a dialog, but without the dialog. There's a few usages of a PXChangeID in Acumatica's own code, but nothing I can find without a dialog popup. If anyone has a working example, I would love to see it.

For those not familiar, if you just change the value and save, it acts like an insert, because it doesn't allow a key value change by default.  Although it makes sense, there should be a way to override this.

Update - tried to use PXDatabase.Update() as suggested in response, but get a runtime error that PMProject is not a valid object name.

```
PXDatabase.Update<PMProject>(
    new PXDataFieldAssign<PMProject.contractCD>(project.ContractCD),
    new PXDataFieldRestrict<PMProjectExtension.usrSharedProjectID>(projectExt.UsrSharedProjectID)
);
```

Comment: Quick answer would be to use PXDatabase.Update and just set the CD value to the new value since in the table its not the key - you should be safe. The ID is the key and used all over

Comment: You could also copy ChangeProjectID class, remove the dialog from Handler and substitute it with your own logic. The magic happens in ChangeCDProject method.

Comment: Just tried using PXDatabase.Update but it tells me that PMProject is an invalid object name.  Huh?

Comment: HB_ACUMATICA -- I searched the source for both ChangeProjectID and ChangeCDProject and found neither.  Do you mean ChangeID?

Comment: In the INItemClassMaint graph, I found a ImmediatelyChangeID class that looked promising, but I can't get that to work either.  It's still creating a new Project on save instead of updating the CategoryCD field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you want to update the CD field I would just use PXDatabase.Update. Calling PXDatabase.Update will update the table as soon as its called - not when the graph is persisted. You will need to refresh your view displaying the project after making the call.

Here is a working example that can be used for any ID/CD table:

```
public static void ChangeCDValue<Dac, IDField, CDField>(int? id, string newCD)
    where Dac : IBqlTable
    where IDField : IBqlField
    where CDField : IBqlField
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(id));
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newCD))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(newCD));
    }

    PXDatabase.Update<Dac>(
        new PXDataFieldAssign<CDField>(newCD),
        new PXDataFieldRestrict<IDField>(PXDbType.Int, id));
}
```

For updating a project CD you can use the Contract DAC like this:

```
ChangeCDValue<PX.Objects.CT.Contract, PX.Objects.CT.Contract.contractID, PX.Objects.CT.Contract.contractCD>(3354, "TESTCHANGE");
```

Similar call to change Inventory CD value:

```
ChangeCDValue<PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem, PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem.inventoryID, PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem.inventoryCD>(10, "NEWCD");
```

Alternatively as *@HB_Acumatica* mentioned in the comments to your question you can make your own version of the `ChangeProjectID` class removing the dialog code. If you are having trouble searching for the class by name it is in the following file in your Acumatica site: App_Data\CodeRepository\PX.Objects\PM\ProjectEntry.cs

Using the code from ChangeProjectID will allow you to update the value in cache and wait to make the change until persist. Visually it should show the change without needing to do your own refresh also.

Comment: There is no ChangeCDValue() in the file you mention, at least for the build I'm using -- 17.210.0034.  Are you referencing a newer version?

Comment: I just looked at a newer version source (18.208.0013) and now see a ChangeCDProject(), but no ChangeCDValue().  I guess I'll take a look at ChangeCDProject() in this newer version to see if it'll help at all.

Comment: I was using 18.206 i think. I think the change ID feature was added in either 18R1 or 18R2 so that would make sense.

Comment: Thanks for your working example. I used that to finally get it to work.  As I mentioned previously, my own PXDatabase.Update() call was returning an error for PMProject. I was also using an extended field as criteria.  Once I changed to use Contract and ContractID in your example it works. I had to query for the ContractID using my extended field first, due to my scenario. I would think how I was originally doing it should also work, though, even though PMProject is a subclass, and a referenced field is an extended field.  Possible bug maybe, but at least it's working now.